# CMake common source files in library

Tags: android, command-line, cmake

I would like to build project in Android using CMake for NDK. I want to add libraries based on some flag, which is visible in CMake with some common part, the result looking like:

```
set(INFERENCE_ENGINE TFLITE)
set(COMMON_FILES "${SRC_DIR}/native-lib.cpp
            ${CRF_SRC}/permutohedral.cpp
            ${CRF_SRC}/unary.cpp
            ${CRF_SRC}/pairwise.cpp
            ${CRF_SRC}/objective.cpp
            ${CRF_SRC}/densecrf.cpp
            ${CRF_SRC}/labelcompatibility.cpp
            ${SRC_DIR}/utils.cpp
            ${SRC_DIR}/jniutils.cpp
            ${SRC_DIR}/timer.cpp
            ${SRC_DIR}/inference.cpp
            ${SRC_DIR}/backend/dcrf.cpp
            ${SRC_DIR}/sky/colorCV.cpp
            ${SRC_DIR}/sky/colorLoop.cpp
            ${neon_SRCS}"
        )

if (${INFERENCE_ENGINE} STREQUAL TFLITE)
    add_library(starfiltersdk SHARED
            ${COMMON_FILES}
            ${SRC_DIR}/backend/tflite.cpp
            )
elseif(${INFERENCE_ENGINE} STREQUAL SNPE)
    add_library(starfiltersdk SHARED
            ${COMMON_FILES}
            ${SRC_DIR}/backend/snpe.cpp
            )
endif()
```

However I get:

```
Cannot find source file:

   src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
             libs/densecrf/src/permutohedral.cpp
             libs/densecrf/src/unary.cpp
             libs/densecrf/src/pairwise.cpp
             libs/densecrf/src/objective.cpp
             libs/densecrf/src/densecrf.cpp
             libs/densecrf/src/labelcompatibility.cpp
             src/main/cpp/utils.cpp
             src/main/cpp/jniutils.cpp
             src/main/cpp/timer.cpp
             src/main/cpp/inference.cpp
             src/main/cpp/backend/dcrf.cpp
             src/main/cpp/sky/colorCV.cpp
             src/main/cpp/sky/colorLoop.cpp
             src/main/cpp/sky/blend.cpp
```

which indicates that  `COMMON_FILES` variable is seen as one file. Do you have any idea how to fix it, or should I use completely different approach (to achieve this common part of add_library)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake distinguishes between quoted arguments and unquoted arguments [1].
By enclosing the list of files in quotes you are creating a single long argument while the `add_library` expects to receive each source file as a separate argument.

Changing the `set(COMMON_FILES ...)` to:

```
set(COMMON_FILES ${SRC_DIR}/native-lib.cpp
        ${CRF_SRC}/permutohedral.cpp
        ${CRF_SRC}/unary.cpp
        ${CRF_SRC}/pairwise.cpp
        ${CRF_SRC}/objective.cpp
        ${CRF_SRC}/densecrf.cpp
        ${CRF_SRC}/labelcompatibility.cpp
        ${SRC_DIR}/utils.cpp
        ${SRC_DIR}/jniutils.cpp
        ${SRC_DIR}/timer.cpp
        ${SRC_DIR}/inference.cpp
        ${SRC_DIR}/backend/dcrf.cpp
        ${SRC_DIR}/sky/colorCV.cpp
        ${SRC_DIR}/sky/colorLoop.cpp
        ${neon_SRCS}
    )
```

should solve the error message you show.

[1] https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#quoted-argument